# How to let the AI trained on MNIST recognize my own hand-written number?

Tags: deep-learning, python, mnist

I have already trained a simple model without using any frameworks to recognize the hand-written numbers from the MNIST dataset. Actually it's just a copy of the example on the book Grokking Algorithms. Here:

```
import sys, numpy as np
from keras.datasets import mnist
(x_train, y_train),(x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

images, labels = (x_train[0:1000].reshape(1000, 28*28)/255,y_train[0:1000])
one_hot_labels = np.zeros((len(labels), 10))
for i, l in enumerate(labels):
    one_hot_labels[i][l] = 1
labels = one_hot_labels

np.random.seed(1)
relu = lambda x:(x>=0)*x
relu2deriv = lambda x: x>= 0
alpha, iterations, hidden_size, pixels_per_image, num_labels = (0.005, 350, 40, 784, 10)
weights_0_1 = 0.2*np.random.random((pixels_per_image, hidden_size))-0.1
weights_1_2 = 0.2*np.random.random((hidden_size, num_labels))-0.1

for j in range(iterations):
    error, correct_cnt = (0.0, 0)
    for i in range(len(images)):
        layer_0 = images[i:i+1]
        layer_1 = relu(np.dot(layer_0, weights_0_1))
        layer_2 = np.dot(layer_1, weights_1_2)
        error+=np.sum((labels[i:i+1]-layer_2)**2)
        correct_cnt += int(np.argmax(layer_2)==np.argmax(labels[i:i+1]))
        layer_2_delta = labels[i:i+1]-layer_2
        layer_1_delta = layer_2_delta.dot(weights_1_2.T)*relu2deriv(layer_1)
        weights_1_2 += alpha*layer_1.T.dot(layer_2_delta)
        weights_0_1 += alpha*layer_0.T.dot(layer_1_delta)
    if j%10==9:
        print(j, str(error/float(len(images))), str(correct_cnt/float(len(images))))
```

After training(without any regularization), the accuracy on the test set is about 83%. It sounds fairly high to me, so I want to test this model on some of my own hand-written numbers. I know the   network takes in a (784, 1) shaped matrix as input, with all elements ranging from 0 to 1. Then I found the website [Pixilart](https://www.pixilart.com/draw) to actually draw several numbers and downloaded them as images with PNG format. Here's one of them:
[image: One of the pictures]

According to [the blog post](https://deepinout.com/numpy/numpy-questions/53_numpy_convert_image_to_a_matrix_in_python.html), I used the following code to load my own pictures and transformed it to a matrix:

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open("C:/users/22432/downloads/it0.png")
n = np.array(img.getdata())
```

Then I noticed it is a 784x4 matrix, with the fourth column having actual numbers, the others '0'. So I did this:

```
n1 = np.array([i[3] for i in n])/255
layer_0 = np.array([n1])
layer_1 = relu(np.dot(layer_0, weights_0_1))
layer_2 = np.dot(layer_1, weights_1_2)
```

The `layer_2` variable should store the results of the recognition. But after several tries, I found that the model behaves unexpectedly poor. There's no problem on the weights, and it's accuracy on the MNIST test set is indeed very high. So there's something wrong with the example I provided. But what's wrong? Is there any more requirements for the sample to be successfully recognized?

This question is indeed very similar to [this one](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/37612/how-can-i-use-my-neural-network-model-trained-on-mnist-database-on-real-word). But I didn't get any satisfying answers. Could anyone help me?